# VB .NET | Interaction with another program

Tags: vb.net

How do I 'interact' with another program that is OUTSIDE of VB?
E.g. Let's say I wanted to change the title of a running program, e.g. Firefox or minimize it/maximize it, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Get a window handle and try [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SWP_(SHOW|HIDE)WINDOW`.

Comment: Look into using the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Comment: @Brian Thank you That's easier then SendMessage

Comment: Would you like me to convert it to an answer that you can mark?

Comment: Actually, Robert Harvey has a much more thorough answer below.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I know but I find the Process class easier.

Comment: @Brian Just tried stuff from the process class, it works :D

Comment: I added an answer below for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer your question (again, I think Robert Harvey has a more thorough answer), you would need to do something like this:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class ProcessWrapper

 Public Sub New() // This will likely be different for you, or you won't need it at all.
    MyBase.New()
 End Sub

 Public Function Start(ByVal someProcess As String) As ProcessInfo // Define process here.
    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(someProcess)  // Invoke your process here.
    Return New ProcessInfo(p)  // Return your ProcessInfo object here.
 End Function

End Class
```

Happy coding and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you will want to send a Windows Message to the other window, using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`.

The documentation for SendMessage is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx.  This will tell you all the different ways that SendMessage can be used.

PInvoke.NET shows the VB.NET signature for the SendMessage function as:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

You can find more information about how to use SendMessage and PostMessage in VB.NET here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19740/Send-strings-to-another-application-by-using-Windo